# forLoop does not accept negative step?

Tags: programming

I try to use `\forLoop` for a countdown sequence:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{idx}
\forLoop[-1]{10}{1}{idx}{\numberstring{idx}\\}
\end{document}
```

But this simply does not do anything. If the step is positive, everything is fine. I looked up the documentation for [`forloop`](http://ftp.roedu.net/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/forloop/forloop.pdf) and in the implementation `\addtocounter` was used to increment/decrement the counter. `\addtocounter` accepts negative values and effectively adds them to a specified counter.

So my question is: what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\forLoop` does `\addtocounter` only if the condition `\value{idx}<1`, with your settings, is satisfied, which is never. The package documentation tells that `\forLoop` is deprecated. So

```
\forloop[-1]{idx}{10}{\value{idx}>0}{\arabic{idx}}
```

should be your choice.